# Rendering low poly model to 2D, make facets stand out more

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting

I am creating 2D images of my model, but I want the facets (I think that is the correct term?) to stand out more, how can I do that?

See the random model below I created as an example.

In the scene on the right, the facets stand out nicely.  However, the rendered version on the left is darker and doesn't show some of the facets up as well.  I want to produce a 2D image that looks much closer to the scene view.

I'm using Cycles if that helps.

Thanks.

[image]

Edit:  Added a test blend file.

[image]

Comment: This is primarily due to lighting and materials.  Is this supposed to be glass/refractory material?  Can you upload your blend?  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Have added a test blend file to my question above.  Nothing special with the material, just a plain color on it.  I tried adding planes with an emission shader to see if that would work, but I still couldn't get it light enough so the facets show up like in the scene view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create contrast in your lighting to bring out the facets. Lighting from the exact same direction of the camera does the opposite, it makes everything flat.

This image I created by starting with your blend file and then:

- Removing the Front Light object
- Removing the Front Light material from the Top/Bottom Light objects
- Increasing the emission strength
- Moving the light objects towards/away from the mesh object until the lighting is nice

[image: just changed lighting]

By adding a bit of glossyness to the mesh material we can bring out the facets even more:

[image: with glossyness]

This is the material node tree:

[image: material node tree]

Answer (score 2):

I was in the middle of posting when two answers showed up :)

In addition to what others have said, the primary reason for your lack of definition is lighting.  I have approximated the light sources used by the ***Material Viewport Shading*** and parented them to the camera so that they move with the camera:

Looking at the sphere, it appears that Blender uses a three-point light system to illuminate objects in the shaded viewport:
[image]

[image]

---

So when using this on your model it looks like this:

[image]

Here's the blend:

[image]